# Do Eidolons gain levels and feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement, summoner, eidolon

Do Eidolon's gain class levels and feats as their summoner becomes stronger or do they just have access to evolution points to get stronger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, they gain Feats.

As the summoner gains levels, their eidolon also gain feats. This can be seen on the eidolon's table for [chained summoners](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/summoner.html) (from *Advanced Players Guide*):

[image]

And also for [unchained summoners](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/unchained/classes/summoner.html) (from *Pathfinder Unchained*):

[image]

But keep in mind that they **do not gain class levels**, instead, they get stronger based on his master's summoner class levels, unlocking extra hit dice, skill points, feats, evolution points and special abilities.

Comment: I never noticed how they changed *Bad Save* to *Poor Save* there.

Comment: Hey shadow, I noticed that you answered the title but not the whole question (in OP's body) in your header. In the body they ask if Eidolons gain class levels (which they do not) so a blanket 'yes' wasn't applicable. I swapped it to specify they do gain Feats.